# How to define drag gesture in property on SwiftUI view

Tags: swiftui, draggesture

I cannot return DragGesture from computed property like below

```
'_EndedGesture<_ChangedGesture<DragGesture>>' to return type 'DragGesture'


 var dimDrag : DragGesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged({
                    print("Dim drag")

                    if $0.translation.width > 0 {
                        self.model.menuOffset = max(min($0.translation.width, UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.7), 0.0)
                    } else {
                        self.model.menuOffset = max(min(UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.7 + $0.translation.width, UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.7), 0.0)
                    }

            })
            .onEnded({
                    if $0.translation.width < -100 {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.model.isMenuOpen = true
                            self.model.menuOffset = 0.0
                        }
                    } else if $0.translation.width > 100 {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.model.isMenuOpen = false
                            self.model.menuOffset = UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.7
                        }
                    }
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is returning `_EndedGesture<_ChangedGesture<DragGesture>>` and not `DragGesture`, one can declare the computed property like this :

```swift
 var dimDrag: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged({
                    if $0.translation.width > 0 {
                        self.model.menuOffset = max(min($0.translation.width, UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.7), 0.0)
                    } else {
                        self.model.menuOffset = max(min(UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.7 + $0.translation.width, UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.7), 0.0)
                    }
            })
            .onEnded({
                    if $0.translation.width < -100 {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.model.isMenuOpen = true
                            self.model.menuOffset = 0.0
                        }
                    } else if $0.translation.width > 100 {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.model.isMenuOpen = false
                            self.model.menuOffset = UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.7
                        }
                    }
            })
    }
```

One can make this variable as part of private extension.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
let myDrag = {
    DragGesture()
        .onChanged({ value in

        })
        .onEnded { value in

        }
    }()
```